# IOS 8 App Group access container app file in Keyboard extension

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, ios-app-group

I want to access container app file in my custom keyboard extension through App Group feature.For That purpose I have create Group ID on my Apple portal and also added it in my both targets(Keyboard and app)
I have successfully access data by `NSUserDefaults` its working fine I can access data. But I am stuck on getting file from container app
I have access URL

```
NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
           containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.company.app"];
```

NSURL Return URL in following way.

```
/Users/AxisCyberTech1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1649BBF4-6615-4E53-BFC9-A3D07F3CA70A/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/49A4F24B-30A8-474E-8FFA-072E0DF61CBD/
```

but this path not access any file from Container source bundle.
How can I access container souce file

Answer (score -2):

There's another restriction for keyboard extension. You should set RequestsOpenAccess to YES in Info.plist then it can access the files.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW2

Answer (score -2):

To get access to containing app bundle is sandboxed and not alloew to access from outside app. Call `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:YOUR_APP_GROUP_ID]` to obtain App Group Shared container's URL.

Note that using `NSFileCoordinator` inside extension to access containing app shared container may cause the deadlock. See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2408/_index.html)